# Error in store procedure execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When I am trying t execute a stored procedure, It is showing this error

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure MA01003_SUM1, Line 12
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Following is the stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[MA01003_SUM1]
as 
Begin

  declare @desc as varchar(50)
  set @desc = dbo.sdescription(1,0,3)


  declare @cost as float
  set @cost = dbo.SCost(0)

 Insert into SummaryLoad(
 SL_TierName,
 SL_CorporateName,
 SL_HospiceName, 
 SL_GroupName,
 SL_DateKey,
 SL_FactAmt,
 SL_AHT,
 SL_headingNo,
 SL_Staffno,
 SL_factno,
 SL_Description,
 SL_Cost) 



 SELECT [MA_TierName]                   
  ,[MA_CorporateName]                   
  ,[MA_HospiceName]                 
  ,[MA_GroupName]                   
  ,[MA_Datekey]                 
  ,SUM([MA_NumContacts]) Contacts                   
  ,SUM([MA_Duration]) ActualHandleTime,
  '1',
  '0',
  '3',              
  @desc,
  @cost

 FROM [DM_ResourceUtilization].[dbo].[MedicationsAdded] 
 GROUP BY [MA_TierName]                 
  ,[MA_CorporateName]                   
  ,[MA_HospiceName]                 
  ,[MA_GroupName]                   
  ,[MA_Datekey] 

  end
```

Comment: What is `dbo.SCost(0)` and `dbo.sdescription(1,0,3)`?

Comment: what does those function returns??

Answer (score 0):

Probable are the chances that data type or width of table SummaryLoad is not matching with that of select statement output. Please see the following script to illustrate the concept -

```
use tempdb 
go 
create table #test ( c1 varchar(5))  
go 
declare @desc as varchar(10)  -- Width is 10 only
set @desc = 'AAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBbbCCCCCCCCCCCCCCcDDDDDDDDDDDDDD'  -- Assigning higher width value
select @desc -- No error thrown, SQL server do the data truncation silently

insert into #test(c1) values ( @desc )  -- Here SQL server throws an error, 
       -- reason - value in @desc is of width 10, but target column width is 5
```

Better you can find the offending column or statement by yourself without much difficulty.  To do this comment out each column and its values from the procedure and then invoke it in a transaction OR give a constant value that would match with the target data type for each column one by one. Sample follows -

```
Insert into SummaryLoad(
 SL_TierName, 
 SL_CorporateName,
 SL_HospiceName, 
 SL_GroupName,
 SL_DateKey,
 SL_FactAmt,
 SL_AHT,
 SL_headingNo,
 SL_Staffno,
 SL_factno,
 SL_Description,
 SL_Cost) 

 SELECT 
  /*[MA_TierName] */ -- Commented out 
   'A'  -- Sample value, alter the procedure with this insert and run in transaction
        -- If that is successful, this is offending column. Change the value with matching 
        -- data type and width of column SL_TierName of table SummaryLoad
        -- Repeat this for all columns till you find the offending column(s)
  ,[MA_CorporateName]                   
  ,[MA_HospiceName]                 
  ,[MA_GroupName]                   
  ,[MA_Datekey]                 
  ,SUM([MA_NumContacts]) Contacts                   
  ,SUM([MA_Duration]) ActualHandleTime,
  '1',
  '0',
  '3',              
  @desc,
  @cost

 FROM [DM_ResourceUtilization].[dbo].[MedicationsAdded] 
 GROUP BY [MA_TierName]                 
  ,[MA_CorporateName]                   
  ,[MA_HospiceName]                 
  ,[MA_GroupName]                   
  ,[MA_Datekey]
```

Modified procedure should be called in a transaction to ensure that your data is not affected by this test. Procedure can be called in a transaction using following statement

```
begin transaction 
exec [dbo].[MA01003_SUM1]
rollback transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your error message :

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure MA01003_SUM1, Line 12
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

It is possibly your column width issue which is overlapped or oveflow then the size defined in column.

So, you have to just check which column have how much size & what you passing the data (i.e. size of data) which greater then size defined in column.